# Welcome emails sent by Frappe framework are missing the port number

Tags: python, nginx, erpnext, frappe

When using Frappe framework and changing the Nginx port from 80 to 8002 to avoid conflicts, I get broken URLs in all emails sent by the system. The port was changed using `bench set-nginx-port 8002`. The ports 80 and 8000 are already busy in the VPS.

While I access the system using hostname:port_number, I get all emails as hostname/the-rest-of-url.

The same issue was reported on [frappe.io](https://discuss.frappe.io/t/email-not-sending-correct-url-on-updating-nginx-port/47290/2) and [GitHub](https://github.com/frappe/erpnext/issues/17044), but it's unclear how to solve it.

How can I solve this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open site_config.json and write `"hostname":"http://<your_hostname>:<your-port-number>"`. For example:

```
{
 "db_name": "your_db_name",
 "db_password": "your_db_password",
 "db_type": "your_db_type",
 "hostname": "http://your_host_name:port_number"
}
```